# Splash screen Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen

I added the logo in different resolutions in folders for splash screen.

When my app start, i see a logo with resolution 280x175 (i uploaded a logo of this resolution, because it looks good). In splash screen its looks diffuse. How can I show the logo in high resolution?

If I add a logo in a higher resolution, it does not fit on the screen.

I need logo in splash screen in size 280px width

I have folders in  **src/main/res**  and uploaded logos there

drawable
resolution logo - 280x175

drawable-v21
resolution logo - 280x175

mipmap-hdpi
resolution logo - 800x480

mipmap-mdpi
resolution logo - 480x320

mipmap-xhdpi
resolution logo - 1280x720

mipmap-xxhdpi
resolution logo - 1600x960

mipmap-xxxhdpi
resolution logo - 1920x1280

My code in folders - drawable and drawable-v21

launch_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

How to change the code so that the logo on the home screen is clear and sharp?

Comment: Which package did you use for the splash screen?
Did you generate the logo with `flutter_launcher_icons`?

Comment: I prepared icons for applications earlier, they are installed correctly, icons are updated everywhere. I have difficulty with the logo on the splash screen. I used appicon.co for create app icon. App icon and the logo that I want to put on the splash screen are different.